# jquery dynamic href based on user_id

Tags: jquery, dynamic, href

I have typed up this little Jquery to dynamically append the href of my billing page based on the users id.

It doesn't seem to be working tho? Hopefully someone can point out my mistake.

Thanks in advance for your help and code snippets.

```
$individualpage="billing".$_SESSION['user_id'].".php";
$("a#billing").attr("href", "$individualpage");
```

Link on page

```
<a href="" id="billing">billing</a>
```

Comment: FYI, you may have a security problem here- would your system accept any number added into a URL, like somebody else's user id?  This setup might allow a user to access or modify another user's account.  You could always access that $_SESSION value for user id when the billing script is accessed.

Comment: I will test out this possible issue. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing JavaScript (a client-side language) with PHP (a server-side language). Remember that PHP is done by the time JavaScript begins.

With that said, try something like this:

*Somewhere in your PHP page:*

```
<?php
  $individualpage="billing".$_SESSION['user_id'].".php";
?>
```

Then, within the HTML of the page, use PHP to dump the value to JavaScript so it can pick up and complete the request:

```
$('a#billing').attr('href','<?= $individualpage; ?>');
```

Although, you're probably better off just dumping it directly in to the `<a>` tag:

```
<a id="billing" href="<?= $individualpage; ?>" ... >...</a>
```

(And skipping JavaScript altogether.)

Comment: Ill give it a shot, thank you for your quick response. Yes, ill skip over JS, id rather take the pure php answer any day

Comment: @webmasteralexl: Awesome. ;-) If you didn't reference an element with an ID (telling me only one element is going to have a change applied) I would stick with JS. But, given you're modifying a single anchor, using the in-line approach is both faster and less error-prone.

Comment: When I tried the pure php vr it didnt work? If I use JS in the answer by Akloboucnik it works fine? Humm...

Comment: @webmasteralexl: depending on settings/php version the short-hand echo may not work. Try this instead: `<?php echo $individualpage; ?>`

Comment: `<script>
$(function() {
    var individualpage="billing<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>.php";
    $("a#billing").attr("href", individualpage);
});
</script>
<a id="billing" class="clientLogin" href="<?= $individualpage; ?>">Billing</a>`

Comment: even with <?php echo $individualpage; ?> it doesn't want to work??

Comment: @webmasteralexl: JavaScript is _always_ going to override whatever PHP is doing. Make sure you remove (or comment) the JS when you go to test the PHP result.

Comment: There we go...works fine now...I just had to move the php script above the line with the href tag in it. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @webmasteralexl: clad to hear it and to help. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your probably mixing PHP and JS code together.

You need

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var individualpage="billing<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>.php";
    $("a#billing").attr("href", individualpage);
});
</script>
```

in your view script.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am going to try Brad's answer of a pure php vr first. It looks like your JS answer would also do what I need.